# How to suppress time part of a .NET DateTime in display if and only if time part = 00:00:00?

Tags: .net, asp.net, datetime, eval, datetime-format

In an ASP.NET page I have this:

```
<asp:Label ID="MyDateTimeLabel" runat="server" 
     Text='<%# Eval("MyDateTime") %>' />
```

I'd like to have it formatted like

```
... Eval("MyDateTime", "{0:d}") ... // Display only the date
```

if and only if the time part of MyDateTime is 00:00:00. Otherwise like this:

```
... Eval("MyDateTime", "{0:g}") ... // Display date and time in hh:mm format
```

Is this possible and how can I do that?

Thank you for hints in advance!

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I'd put this in my code-behind:

```
// This could use a better name!
protected string FormatDateHideMidnight(DateTime dateTime) {
    if (dateTime.TimeOfDay == TimeSpan.Zero) {
        return dateTime.ToString("d");
    } else {
        return dateTime.ToString("g");
    }
}
```

And change the .aspx to call that:

```
<asp:Label ID="MyDateTimeLabel" runat="server" 
     Text='<%# FormatDateHideMidnight((DateTime)Eval("MyDateTime")) %>' />
```

If you do this in multiple places, consider writing [an extension method](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb383977.aspx) for `DateTime` and put this logic there (perhaps with additional parameters to supply different formats, etc.).

Comment: Thanks for the link to "extension methods". I don't know what this is (except I've heard the term), I'll take a look. Actually yes, I'd like to use this DateTime format on several places and in several pages. I've placed the code into a tool namespace and static class. Works also fine so far.

Comment: Excellent - they're a great tool. Good luck!

Comment: @Atomiton - thank you, and feel free to edit stuff like that right in, if it ever comes up again in my answers. :)

Comment: Argh! I would have... as I believe the reduction of comment noise is a good thing... but I think that's a 2000pt action. ( I was on the verge of 1000pt when the minimum was upped ) 877k to go!

Answer (score 1):

didn't test, but off the top of my head:

in markup

```
<asp:Label ID="MyDateTimeLabel" runat="server" 
     Text='<%# FormatMyDateTime((DateTime)Eval("MyDateTime")) %>' />
```

in code-behind:

```
protected string FormatMyDateTime(DateTime date)
{
      // Do your if else for formatting here.
}
```

Comment: Thanks, it works fine, except in markup "...as DateTime" needs to be replaced by "...as DateTime?" (also the DateTime parameter in code-behind must be DateTime?) because the "as" operator requires either a reference type or a nullable type (the debugger was telling me).

Comment: Well, if `MyDateTime` is a `DateTime`, the correct way would be to use a "regular" cast (`(DateTime)Eval("MyDateTime")`) instead of `as`.

Comment: The `as` operator cannot be used with `DateTime` because it's a non-nullable value type.

Comment: @João - Thanks for pointing that out... like I said, "didn't test, but off the top of my head:" ;)

Comment: @Heinzi: In my project MyDateTime can be nullable and non-nullable as well. So in the non-nullable case I would use your proposal '(DateTime)Eval("MyDateTime")', but for nullable datetimes 'Eval("MyDateTime") as DateTime?'. The method in code-behind I need only once as "FormatMyDateTime(DateTime? datetime)". It works with nullable datetime and non-nullable datetime too. (I have to catch the null case in the method then before formatting of course). Is this the way to go?

Comment: @Slauma: Sounds good to me. BTW, it works because `DateTime` can be implicitly converted to `DateTime?`.

Comment: OK, thank you!

By the way and off-topic: How do you all mark code with that grey background here in the comments?

Answer (score 1):

You did not mention which .net language you use. With VB.NET, you can use the following inline expression:

```
... Text='<%# Eval("MyDateTime", If(Eval("MyDateTime").TimeOfDay = TimeSpan.Zero, "{0:d}", "{0:g}")) %>'
```

I did not test with C#, but I guess replacing `If(...)` with the ternary `?:` operator and casting the result of `Eval` to a `DateTime` before accessing `TimeOfDay` should do the trick.

Answer (score 0):

I am not sure if you are looking for this, but I feel it's worth trying.
Hope it works.

```
<%# String.Format(Eval("MyDateTime"),"{0:d}") %>

<%# String.Format(Eval("MyDateTime"),"{0:g}") %>
```

Answer (score 0):

You can substitute the following code in the aspx file or create a method and call the method to return the value.

```
<%
   DateTime dtTime = DateTime.Now;

    if (dtTime.TimeOfDay == TimeSpan.Zero)
        Response.Write(String.Format("{0:d}", dtTime));
    else
        Response.Write(String.Format("{0:g}", dtTime));
%>
```

Answer (score 0):

To show only date part

```
<asp:Label id="lblExamDate" runat="server" Text='<%#Convert.ToDateTime(Eval("theExamDate.Date")).ToShortDateString()%>'></asp:Label>
```

and to show only time part

```
<asp:Label ID="lblStartTime" runat="server" Text='<%#Convert.ToDateTime(Eval("ExamStartTime")).ToShortTimeString()%>' />
```